# Install OpenSSL 1.1.1g in Ubuntu 16.04.06 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, ubuntu-16.04

I followed the instructions in https://cloudwafer.com/blog/installing-openssl-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/ but i get always an older openssl version when i run openssl version. In my case the 1.1.1e. It compiles and installs well but it seems that Ubuntu keeps using a previous installed version. How to fix this?
Thank you.

The problem only occurs in one server which had the 1.1.1.e installed:

```
openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1e  17 Mar 2020 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020)
built on: Mon Aug 10 21:54:27 2020 UTC
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) idea(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DZLIB -DNDEBUG
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/local/ssl/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

Comment: How did you determine that "Ubuntu keeps using a previous installed version"?

Comment: Go back through the tutorial, and this time do the steps you skipped the first time.

Comment: I did not skipped steps. In other servers the problem did not occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/ssl/lib"
```

Now the crontab can run the openssl correctly.